# PHP syntax error "t_encapsed"

Tags: php

The section of code that it is saying has an error

```
 $data = "<?php 
\$username = '$_SESSION['username']';
\$password = '$newPassword';
?>";
```

The error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier `(T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in`C:\Users\ross\Desktop\Xampp\htdocs\files\password.php on line 15

Please Help

Comment: Despite the fact that this is some kind of bad code, try to separate `<` and `?` and concatenate them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dollars in the string.

```
<?php

$data = "<?php 
\$username = '\$_SESSION['username']';
\$password = '\$newPassword';
?>";
```

In case you actually mean them to be interpreted as variables, use {} for the session - but they, of course, must be defined, else it will fail.

```
<?php

$data = "<?php 
\$username = '{$_SESSION['username']}';
\$password = '$newPassword';
?>";
```

However, generating PHP in PHP looks fishy. Surely you're employing some dirty practice.

Comment: no im storeing user passwords i a php files insted of a data base.you can not view the php file as it is a vairbule

Comment: Still a poor practice. The rule of thumb is to never ever store passwords, just their hashes. Unless you need the passwords for some external login service, ofc.

Comment: i plan to use hashes later i am just experimenting i am sort of new to php

Comment: Alright, still using database would be easier. Try SQLite, it lives in a file, so it's easy to setup and use.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `$_SESSION['username']` to `$_SESSION[username]` ;)